# Let a circle with diameter $AB$ have points $C$ and $D$ on same side so that $BD$ bisects $\angle CBA$. Chords $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at $E$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, problem-solving

> Let a circle with diameter $AB$ have points $C$ and $D$ on same side so that $BD$ bisects $\angle CBA$. Chords $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at $E$. Given that $AE = 169$ cm and $EC = 119$ cm, find $ED$.

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

We have $AE = 169, EC = 119$. 
Let $AB = r$ , $DE = x$ , $AD = y$ , $BC = z$ , $BE = a$.
Now, applying Pythagoras Theorem gives all these equations one by one :-
$$(i) x^2 + y^2 = 169^2$$
$$(ii) z^2 + 119^2 = a^2$$
$$(iii) (x+a)^2 + y^2 = R^2$$
$$(iv) 288^2 + z^2 = R^2$$
We also have $\Delta CEB \sim \Delta DAB \sim \Delta DAE$ . They give information as :-
$$(i) \frac{CE}{DA} = \frac{CB}{DB} = \frac{EB}{AB}$$
$$(ii) \frac{DE}{EC} = \frac{DA}{CB} = \frac{AE}{EB}$$

The Problem is that all these don't really make me find the value of $ED$, or I am unable to find it by using them appropriately in some way.

Can anyone help me? Thank You.

Comment: Hint :drop a perpendicular from $E$ to $AB$. the length of that perpendicular will be equal to $EC$. the rest is easy

Comment: How will I show it? or prove it?

Comment: $CEB=90-x, BEQ=90-x$ and they have a common side

Comment: Where is $Q$, can you show me? Also how will that perpendicular help?

Comment: $Q$ is the  foot of the perpendicular and you can calculate $QA$  with pythagoras

Comment: Ok you can find $QA$ , but how will you find $ED$ ? Am I missing something?

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $Q$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $E$ to $AB$ then  $EC=EQ$ ,  $AQ^2 = AE^2-EQ^2 $ and $$\frac{AQ} {EQ} =\frac{AC} {CB}$$  You can calculate $EB$ by pythagoras from $\triangle EBC$ , and finally $$AE \cdot EC= EB \cdot DE$$

Answer (score 1):

By angle bisector rule $$\frac{CB}{AB}=\frac{119}{169}$$ also by Pythagoras $$AB^2+CB^2={(169+119)}^2$$ $$AB=?,CB=?$$ Now in $\Delta CEB $ $$\tan x=\frac{119}{CB}=?$$ From here you can find
$\sin x$ but $$\sin x=\frac{DE}{169}$$

We are done!

Comment: Same as others +1

Answer (score 1):

Let $AB = 169y$, $BC=119y$.

$$AC^2=AB^2-BC^2\Rightarrow y^2=\ldots$$

$$BE^2=CE^2+BC^2\Rightarrow BE^2=\ldots$$

$$DE\cdot BE = AE\cdot CE \Rightarrow DE=\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Note $ DE \cdot EB = AE \cdot EC =169\cdot 119 $, or
$$DE \cdot (DB -DE)  =169\cdot 119$$
Substitute  $$DB = AB \cos x= AB \cdot\frac{\sin 2x}{2\sin x}=AB \cdot\frac{\frac{AC}{AB}}{2\frac{DE}{AE}}= \frac{144\cdot169}{DE}$$
to get
$$DE^2= 169\cdot(144-119)=169\cdot 25=(13\cdot5)^2$$
Thus, $DE=65$.